# OTPCredential returns empty credential in angular

Tags: angular, web, one-time-password

I have implemented the OTPCredential API into my angular application like

```
  /**
   * listens for the one time token
   */
  laodOtpApi() {
    if ('OTPCredential' in window) {
      navigator.credentials
        .get({
          //@ts-ignore
          otp: { transport: ['sms'] },
          signal: this.abortController.signal,
        })
        .then((content) => {
          console.log('got otp from client', JSON.stringify(content));
          //@ts-ignore
          this.token.patchValue(content.code);
        });
    }
  }
```

I receive the sms in my android phone and the message "send 417618 to MyComputer". But the console.log of content returns an empty object: `got otp from client {}`

The application is served via an secure endpoint, so I am not sure if there is something wrong on phone side or the application side...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple: there is no way to print it like JSON (at least the way like above does not work).

If you call `console.log(content)` or `console.log(content.code)` it works fine....